# how to replace the typescript alias when compile

Tags: typescript

I define the typescript alias in `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"paths": {
      "@net/*":["net/*"],
      "@auth/*":["auth/*"],
    },
```

then using this alias in `index.ts` like this:

```
import { ResponseHandler } from "@net/rest/ResponseHandler";
export { ResponseHandler };
```

when compile the typescript project, I want to replace the alias `@net` to the project real path like this `../net/rest/ResponseHandler` so that the project path could parse correctly when using in other project as a lib. how to replace the alias name? I have tried using [tsc-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-alias) by using this command after installed the `tsc-alias` lib:

```
"tscbuild": "tsc && tsc-alias",
```

but it did not replace the `@net`, what should I do to replace the typescript alias success? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to replace the path using `tsc-alias`. But you can tried to install `ttypescript`:

```
yarn add ttypescript --save-dev
```

and replace your tscbuild command like this:

```
"tscbuild": "ttsc",
```

I have tried and it could succesfully replace the path like `@net` to `../src/net/`.